# what am i doing wrong i am new to coding and cant figure out what this error is

Tags: python, selenium, import, selenium-chromedriver

[screenshot of pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ern.png)

trying to figure out what this error is
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: The way you write webdriver.Chrome(path) should be webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path).

Comment: Its best to copy/paste the program and the traceback error message into the question. As noted, you need to include a driver such as Chrome in the call. Are you following a tutorial? Either its wrong or you need to work the details a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to use `chrome()` function but it is in fact a sub-module, what you want to do is call the `Chrome()` function (notice the capital letter), so your code would look like this:

```
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")
```